# Is N stored as a memory address in the register or as an integer?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

Say `%esi` is the register storing the function argument `int n`. Does `%esi` store `n` as an integer in hex or as a memory address?

Comment: Whether its the value or its address depends on the language, calling convention, and signature of the function (call by value/call be reference).  Also, it would be binary, not hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

Hex is a human readable serialization form (e.g. for printing to a console).

Integer is also an interpretation of bits, for example, unsigned vs. signed.

Internally, the computer stores everything as binary-bit strings.  So, `%esi` is just a string of 32 binary digits — though the bits are ordered: starting from one designated as the [least significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit) and going on up to the most significant bit.

These 32-bits could represent a 32-bit address, a 32-bit unsigned integer, a 32-bit signed integer, a 32-bit floating point value, an enum, as many as 4 bytes or ascii characters, or some other bit pattern, like a packed field, or a machine instruction.

The interpretation is not really up to the register itself but the program that uses it — encoded within the instruction sequences of its machine code.

---

In [Instruction Set Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), all the available stateful resources, like CPU registers, have to be looked at from the lens of the instructions — as they are essentially the only way to access the (processor & memory) state.

So, if the instruction set allows dereferencing of a register, then it might reasonably be used to hold an address or pointer.  And if the instruction set supports multiplication of the register, it might reasonably hold an index, a signed or an unsigned integer.

If the instruction set does not support some operations — for example, x86 does not support 32-bit floating point arithmetic on `%esi` — these registers *still* might be used to hold a 32-bit floating point value in transition (e.g. being copied from one location to another without arithmetic).

---

So, to understand how to encode `n` into `%esi` we need to know the data type (such as signed or unsigned) and then the encoding method for that data type.  From that follows the bit pattern that would be held in `%esi`'s ordered string of 32 bits.  This wikipedia article documents numerous encoding methods for [signed integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), for example.  The most popular is for signed (and `int` is signed) is 2's complement (and for unsigned is just the simple binary (base 2) interpretation of successively significant bits).

Answer (score 1):

`int n` is passed by value in asm the same as in C, in all calling conventions, because it fits in a register.

Calling conventions only introduce "hidden" references for wider types (pass a pointer even when the C semantics are pass by value).

(Or even for small structs in some calling conventions.  Buf if you have an arg in ESI as part of the calling convention, you're using the x86-64 System V ABI which does pass small structs in up to 2 registers.)

> in hex or as a memory address?

That makes no sense, those aren't alternatives.  Hex is a text serialization format for numbers (especially binary numbers).

Hex is a useful way to print a value or a pointer to a value.

Numbers in registers are never in hex, but hex is a useful way for tools like debuggers to *print* them so humans can look at them.

If a number *was* stored in hex, it would take twice as much space: one ASCII hex digit per 4-bit nibble of the number represented by the string.